# Scrapy does not find text in Xpath or Css

Tags: css, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been at this one for a few days, and no matter how I try, I cannot get scrapy to abstract text that is in one element.

to spare you all the code, here are the important pieces. The setup does grab everything else off the page, just not this text.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
start_url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g34416-d12428323-On_the_Beach_Wide_flat_beach_Sunsets_Gulf_view_Sharks_teeth_Shells_Fish-Manasota_Key_F.html"

#BASIC ITEM AND SPIDER YADA, SPARE YOU THE DETAILS

hxs = Selector(response)
response_css = response.css("body")

desc_data = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="DETAILS_TRUNC_TEXT"]//text()').extract()
desc_data2 = response_css.css('#DETAILS_TRUNC_TEXT::text').extract()
```

both return empty lists. Yes, I found the xpath and css selector via chrome, but the rest of them work just fine as I'm able to find other data on the site. Please help me find out why this isn't working.

Comment: not sure about Scrapy , but selenium doesn't return elements `//text()` directly from xpath, probably here is the same issue. Try to find just an element with locator like you did `el = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="DETAILS_TRUNC_TEXT"]').extract()` and get text from the element, like `el.text`, is that possible?

Comment: yea, the text() is a scrapy function that only abstracts the text  It doesn't work without that function either.

Answer (score 3):

To get the data you need to use any browser simulator like `selenium` so that It can catch the response of dynamically generated content. You need to put some delay to let the webpage load it's content fully. This is how you can go:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy import Selector
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
URL = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g34416-d12428323-On_the_Beach_Wide_flat_beach_Sunsets_Gulf_view_Sharks_teeth_Shells_Fish-Manasota_Key_F.html"
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(5) #If you take out this line you won't get anything because the content of that page take some time to get loaded.

sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
item = sel.css('#DETAILS_TRUNC_TEXT::text').extract() #It is working
item_ano = sel.xpath('//*[@id="DETAILS_TRUNC_TEXT"]//text()').extract() #It is also working
print(item, item_ano)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it with using splash but this was another great way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your xpath and css in scrapy shell, and got nothing also.

Then I used `view(response)` command and found out the site is dynamic.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

You can see that the details under Overview doesn't show up, and that's why no matter how you try, you still got nothing.

Solutions: Try Selenium (check the solution that SIM provided in the last answer) or Splash.

Good Luck. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll go the splash route, prehaps put some fake scrolls in it via a lua script. Cheers

Comment: `view(response)` was a really useful tip!