# Unable to find path to selector in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

What is the best way to find the path for either CSS or Xpath to get a particular element from an HTML response using Scrapy?

> I am trying to collect data from [twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/hashtag/cats). I am using Scrapy (*I
>   am fairly new to it*). I trying to find the selector path to the
>   tweets under the `data-testid="tweet"` but every path I try on the
>   scrapy shell gives a none_type result. I first tried writing the path
>   on my own but I guess I was doing it wrong. Then I tried
>   right-clicking and copying the path (*I tried it with both **CSS** and
>   **Xpath***) but still no luck.
>
> I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756707/scrapy-does-not-find-text-in-xpath-or-css#) Stack Overflow post, but that did not work
>   either.

Answer (score 1):

You get all the tweets with :

```
//div[@data-testid="tweet"]//div[@lang]
```

To get the text and hashtags for each tweet, use the function string :

```
string(//div[@data-testid="tweet"]//div[@lang])
```

Iterate with a loop to get everything you need :

```
 string((//div[@data-testid="tweet"]//div[@lang])[i])
```

If you just want the text (no hashtags) :

```
//div[@data-testid="tweet"]//div[@lang]/span[string-length(text())>1]
```

Comment: This path does find the right thing on the chrome developer tools, but when I write response.xpath('//div[@data-testid="tweet"]')              in the scrapy shell ,It still returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text, you need to go deeper to the address where the text is. For example:

response.xpath("//div[@class='js-tweet-text-container']/p[@class='TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-text']/text()").getall()

Also works:

response.xpath("//p[@class='TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-text']/text()").getall()

Comment: Firstly, I do understand that to extract the exact data I will have to dig deep, I am having problem filtering out the part of each tweet and then build the data on it as the crawler proceeds on the data provided in the tweet like the user and number of comments, etc. Secondly, I have no clue what this XPath refers to. I tried getting the response out myself but it returned nothing. What does this path point out to?

Comment: I tested it on a Twitter page and it read the text of the tweets. If you can't read the data, there is some other problem. Does Scrapy shell response.body find all page content? If it does, you just need to follow the path to XPath for information.

Comment: Yes, the response.body does return the required output but now that I have thoroughly checked, even for the correct XPath, it returns an empty list. Any idea, how to troubleshoot this?